# Code design. Multicast delegate to the rescue?

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm currently struggling with a design issue and I'm looking for some advice :)
Imagine I have a collection of INotificationHandler objects and the interface is defined as follows:

```
public interface INotificationHandler
{
    void Notify(string message);
}
```

Now I want to call Notify(...) for each INotificationHandler instance. I thought of using a multicast delegate for that. However only recently I stumbled across a piece of code where *expression trees* where used for a similiar task (I imagine)... unfortunately I cannot remember where I saw that piece of code :(

***My key concern is performance as this type of method call would occur quite frequently.***
As this runs in a web application context, can I be sure every instance's method was called?

***The ultimate goal is to have one single "wrapper" class to invoke all other instances of a certain interface type.*** I thought about applying this to logging as well...

```
    ILogger dispatcher.Trace(...)  // does nothing itself, only calls other existing ILogger instances.
    --> calls NLogLogger(:ILogger).Trace(...)
    --> calls SomeOtherLogger(:ILogger).Trace(...)
    --> calls SomeOtherLogger2(:ILogger).Trace(...)
    --> calls SomeOtherLogger3(:ILogger).Trace(...)
```

My motivation to do something like that is to implement a NullObject pattern where I can be sure that any call to my ILogger (which will always be my delegating dispatcher class) will succeed. And secondly ***the number of living ILogger instances will vary depending on application configuration.***

Any feedback is very appreciated :)
Btw.. is there any known pattern for this? Couldn't think of one...

Comment: did you look at the reactive extensions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/gg577609.aspx

Comment: If you want to do it just for logging consider instead using existing configuration system for logging you are using - most logging libraries allow multiple listeners already, wrapping it with another layer of interfaces is fun but feels wasteful. Otherwise you should be able to generate IL on the fly (or delegates/expressions) to call each method of interface you are wrapping.

Comment: Take the .NET INotifyCollectionChanged interface as a guiding example.  Note how its CollectionChanged member is an *event*, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the **[Mediator](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx)** design pattern.

You can register a `callback` for a given message:

```
Mediator.Instance.Register(callback, message);
```

And then when you notify a given message all the registered callbacks are called:

```
Mediator.Instance.NotifyColleagues(message, parameters);
```

Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern) using `Action<object>` delegates, but it is more recommended to use [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.weakreference.aspx) instead of `delegates` to ensure garbage collection.